# Jmeter: What possible load can be generated? (Hardware dependent calculation possible?)

Tags: jmeter, load, hardware, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0

A customer of ours wants to know what possible load we can generate with the following configuration and a Jmeter server?

```
RAM: 32GB
CPU Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1246 v3 @ 3.50GHz
```

Is there somewhere a calculation table or an overview how much load per hardware is possible?

Answer (score 2):

The answer varies depending on the nature of your test, most probably it would be "thousands", however it depends on:

- request and response size
- presence, number and nature of [PreProcessors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#preprocessors), [PostProcessors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors), [Assertions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#assertions), [Timers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers)
- performance tuning of operating system, [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine), JMeter

So only you can answer and only you can measure it, the suggested steps are:

1. Make sure to follow [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)
2. Make sure to monitor baseline OS health metrics (CPU, RAM, Network, Disk IO, etc.), you can use i.e. [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test/) for this
3. Start your test with 1 virtual user and gradually increase the load at the same time looking into the operating system metrics
4. Once any of monitored metrics start exceeding i.e. 80% of available maximum capacity mention how many users were online at this time using i.e. [Active Threads Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/) listener - this is how many users you can simulate from particular this machine for particular this test. For another test you will need to re-run the exercise.